# Can i add date time for sublime snippet?

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to create a snippet that will add a file comment, but I want the snippet to create the DateTime automatically. Can a sublime snippet do that?

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/**
 * Author:      $1
 * DateTime:    $2
 * Description: $3
 */

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>/header</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.css,source.js,source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Tools > New Plugin

Paste this:

```
import datetime, getpass
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class AddDateCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B %Y (%A)") } )

class AddTimeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") } )
```

Save it as ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/add_date.py

Then, in Preferences > Key Bindings - User , add:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+,"], "command": "add_date" },
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+."], "command": "add_time" },
```

You can customize the argument passed to `strftime` [to your liking](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: @aisensiy you might want to change the accepted answer

Comment: @aisensiy: this REALLY should be the accepted answer man.  You need to change that! Thanks @nachocab!

Comment: Note that this is a macro and doesn't answer @aisensiy's question. They want a snippet that has today's date. As opposed to a macro that generates a snippet without todays date.

Comment: Note that plugin files must be saved directly under User, not a subdirectory, unlike snippets and themes.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Sublime Text 3, anyone having the same problem and know a way around it? Positive that I made the changes exactly as listed and saved the files to the right spots. Maybe the syntax changed.

Answer (score 13):

Nachocab, that was a GREAT answer - and helped me VERY much.  I created a slightly different version for myself

**~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/datetimestamp.py:**

```
import datetime, getpass
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AddDateTimeStampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") } )

class AddDateStampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") } )

class AddTimeStampCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", { "contents": "%s" %  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") } )
```

**Preferences > Key Bindings - User:**

```
{"keys": ["super+alt+ctrl+d"], "command": "add_date_time_stamp" },
{"keys": ["super+alt+d"], "command": "add_date_stamp" },
{"keys": ["super+alt+t"], "command": "add_time_stamp" }
```

I wouldn't have been able to do this without your help!  I scoured google for about an hour now and finally was graced by your answer! Thank's so much!

Comment: Anytime @Jonny :)  Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check the InsertDate package: https://github.com/FichteFoll/InsertDate

In the readme you can find an example of how you can use [macros to insert timestamps into snippets](https://github.com/FichteFoll/InsertDate#snippet-macros).

Answer (score 4):

I just implement this function (on **sublime3**) by a simple plugin and the metadata file (.tmPreference file), but I don't know whether this is efficient. There is the way,

**1. create a .tmPreference file, put some variables you want to use in snippets.**
There is an example, you can save the cotent in *Packages*/User/Default.tmPreference

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Global</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string />
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_YEAR</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>2019</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_DATE</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>2019-06-15</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_TIME</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>22:51:16</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**2. create a plugin, which will update the shell variables in .tmPreference file when the plugin loaded.**

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import time
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# everytime when plugin loaded, it will update the .tmPreferences file.
def plugin_loaded():
    # res = sublime.load_resource('Packages/User/Default.tmPreferences')
    # root = ET.fromstring(res)
    meta_info = sublime.packages_path() + '\\User\\Default.tmPreferences'
    tree = ET.parse(meta_info)
    eles = tree.getroot().find('dict').find('dict').find('array').findall('dict')

    y = time.strftime("%Y", time.localtime())
    d = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime())
    t = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())

    for ele in eles:
        kvs = ele.getchildren()
        if kvs[1].text == 'TM_YEAR':
            if kvs[3].text != y:
                kvs[3].text = y
                continue
        elif kvs[1].text == 'TM_DATE':
            if kvs[3].text != d:
                kvs[3].text = d
                continue
        elif kvs[1].text == 'TM_TIME':
            if kvs[3].text != t:
                kvs[3].text = t
                continue

    tree.write(meta_info)
```

**3. use the shell variable you defined in .tmPreference file.**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * \brief      ${1:}
  * \file       $TM_FILENAME
  * \date       $TM_DATE
  * \details    
  ******************************************************************************
  */

${0:}

/****************************** Copy right $TM_YEAR *******************************/
        ]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>cfc</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.c, source.c++</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>c file comment</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: this looks like the correct answer in particular to what OP asked. albeit looks like something for Sublime 2 rather than 3

Comment: yes, i'm working on sblime3. before i got this solution, i was trying to search answers in stackoverflow, and found this post. so I just post my solution here.

Comment: erratum: code is looking for meta_info = sublime.packages_path() + '\\User\\Default.tmPreferences' but you have the file as Default.tmPreferences

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SMART Snippets](https://github.com/BoundInCode/SMART-Snippets) plugin for Sublime Text 2.

> With SMART Snippets, You can now use Python to dynamically create
>   snippets

I did some research for another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768169/get-todays-date-from-sublime-2/12768450#12768450) and I am pretty sure this plugin could solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

It solved in https://github.com/ngocjr7/sublime-snippet-timestamp

Copy all file to Packages/User directory of sublime text.

Configure sublime-snippet file as you want ( cpp_template.sublime-snippet for c++ and py_template.sublime-snippet for python)

Now you can create a simple snippet and the date will be updated every time you press command + s. command + s still has the function to save files.

Explaination

Because snippet doesnot support dynamic variable, I use static variable DATE define in Default.tmPreferences and update this variable when we want to create snippet.

I use a plugin (command) updatetm to update DATE in Default.tmPreferences.

I want the date and time to be updated automatically or at least passive. So I added a function that called updatetm command for keystrockes command + s. To do this, I use another plugin is chain.py to call multiple command on a keymap (both updatetm command and the default command (save). Keymap defined in Default (OSX).sublime-snippet file.

Answer (score -4):

This [post on the official ST forum](https://sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7577) answers your question and provides a close alternative.

In summary, no, you cannot currently insert datetime from a ST snippet.

Comment: Oh, netbeans can... What a pity.

Comment: Yea, I agree. You should submit a feature request: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/

Comment: Yes you can, see my answer below