# Get today's date from Sublime 2

Tags: shell, code-snippets, sublimetext2

I'm a Sublime Text newbie, I was using Textmate before and there I had a handy 'today' command that was returning today's date in the editor (using the shell).

```
eg 'today' + TAB ==> '12/10/2012/'
```

How would I create something like that in Sublime?

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text 2 has a feature called Snippets, this allows for only static 'expression' + TAB replacements.

It seems someone is working on a plugin called [SMART Snippets](https://github.com/BoundInCode/SMART-Snippets) in which you can use python code in the Snippets.

> With [SMART Snippets](https://github.com/BoundInCode/SMART-Snippets), You can now use Python to dynamically create
>   snippets.

The python code in your SMART snippet would be something like:

````
###regex: no
###params: no
###trigger: today
```from time import gmtime, strftime
insert(strftime("%d/%m/%Y", gmtime()))```
````

This now works in my Sublime Text 2 by typing "today + TAB"

Comment: Added installation instructions for SMART_Snippets on the github issue forum: https://github.com/BoundInCode/SMART-Snippets/issues/1

Comment: seems like a good idea - however I can't get it to work. No snippets display, and the create snippet throws an error..

Comment: Seems AGS and me got it working and the SMART Snippets hasnt changes since 10 months, think you are doing something wrong :) but possible Sublime Text 2 has changed and Smart Snippets does not work anymore.